# First use of a vampire rising straight up stiff-bodied from the coffin

Tags: history-of, vampire

I think I first saw it on Mexican vampire movies from the 50s and 60s...but what is the first use of the trope(?) of the vampire rising from the coffin stiff as a board like  in *rigor mortis*?

Leslie Nielson mocked it in this clip from "*Dracula: Dead and Loving it*.

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ChineseVampire

Comment: @DavidW Extremely interesting.

Comment: Are you looking for movies only?

Comment: @paul23 Henhn?  Is there some other format I am ignoring? Or do you mean series?

Comment: Books, stories?

Comment: @paul23 I am sure nobody here will slight you for posting an answer based on books.

Comment: @Rattler oh I don't know, I am merely interested in how old books talk about this. Like old folklore how did that envision those creatures, with the accepted answer this path has be shut off though.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It would seem this is most likely traced back to [*Nosferatu*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0013442/) (1922). Count Orlok rises from the coffin like this when aboard the ship. You can watch the scene below:

Comment: I think you nailed it, but will wait to check off to abide with site policy. Funnily, I did this movie in Film Studies in 1972, but did not remember the scene.

Comment: @Rattler I found a suggestion that the stiff-limbed monster depiction originated in *The Cabinet of Dr. Caligari* 2 years before this, but I didn't post it as an answer, since Cesare wasn't a vampire.

Comment: Even still @DavidW, that was an astute observation. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidW CC Rattler: _The Golem_ (1920) has the stiff rising thing in it but it’s not a vampire so again why I didn’t post it.

Comment: I wonder if the rising in *Nosferatu* was inspired/an homage to any of those other movies...?

Comment: @Rattler "I think you nailed it" - very funny

Comment: What's with those captions?

Comment: @AzorAhai I did not even notice them! Just the first clip of the scene I found.